# Meaning of "converse in secular German"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does **"converse in secular German"** in the following sentence mean "to speak German which was a secular language then"? And does **"secular"** mean "nonreligious" here?

Context

> As one of the ‘wise men’ of his Berlin community, Mendelssohn urged his
>   fellow Jews to adopt the customs of the country in which they had
>   chosen to be resident and to converse in ‘secular German’.

Comment: I think it means not to speak in a way that would be particular to Jews. Yes, here it means non religious. You can get the context from "customs of the country in which they had chosen to be resident" - it means that they've come to the place from elsewhere and the wise man wants his fellow mates to converse in a way that wouldn't incite the native people of the place.

Comment: Probably Mendelssohn did not use the English word "secular", but some German word.  Then "secular" was chosen by a translator for this English version.

Answer (score 4):

In the context of the 19th Century and being Jewish, he was probably referring to speaking German as spoken by secular society rather than the German dialect of [Yiddish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiddish#Secularization).

Comment: Exactly: "secular" doesn't mean "non-religious" here, it really means "non-Jewish", where "Jewish" refers to the larger culture of the Jews, including non-religious Yiddish terms, rather than the Jewish *religion*.

Answer (score 1):

As fdb has helpfully pointed out, the reference is to Moses Mendelssohn who lived in the 18th century.

Yiddish is actually short for **"Yiddish-Teitsch" (Jewish German)** as [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiddish) shows us. Mendelssohn himself most likely did not say the sentence in English. There are several words that are commonly translated into English as secular. Thus Mendelssohn's meaning cannot be properly discerned from the English translation.

However considering that Yiddish-Teitsch can be easily be conceived as counterpart to any other way to speak German. He was an advocate of Jews speaking German and to this end translated the Tora into German.

> To this end Mendelssohn undertook his German translation of the Pentateuch and other parts of the Bible. This work was called the Bi'ur (the explanation) (1783) and also contained a commentary, only that on Exodus having been written by Mendelssohn himself. **The translation was in an elegant High German, designed to allow Jews to learn the language faster.** Most of the German Jews in that period spoke Yiddish and many were literate in Hebrew (the original language of the scripture). - [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Mendelssohn#Works_on_religion_and_civil_society)

Comment: You may have correctly identified the individual concerned, but I don't know how you can be so sure. And his identity isn't particularly relevant to the question.

Comment: I think the quotation is about the Jewish philosopher Moses Mendelssohn, not the composer Felix Mendelssohn. The former, not the latter, was "one of the ‘wise men’ of his Berlin (Jewish) community".

Comment: @fdb you are probably right. I mixed the information 19th century from the other answer somehow with the OP's information. That would've excluded Moses Mendelssohn.

Comment: @fdb I changed the answer to match the more likely Mendelssohn